# Why does Luke leave the wampa’s cave?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

In the first act of The Empire Strikes Back, Luke Skywalker is attacked and captured by a large bipedal creature called a wampa that hangs him unconscious from the roof of its lair in anticipation, it seems, of eating him. Luke awakens, retrieves his light saber, frees himself, and chops off the creature’s arm. He then runs out of the cave onto the icy wastes of Hoth and nearly freezes to death.

Why? Why does he run out of the cave? He still has the light saber. Killing the wampa would have been trivial (it may have been dying from exsanguination already). The cave was sheltered, comparatively warm, potentially contained food. And yet he flees. Help me understand.

Comment: That the Wampa will die from exsanguination soon is highly unlikely. Lightsabers tend to cauterize wounds they inflict. On the other side it may experience a shock from loosing the limb and die from it.

Comment: @EarlGrey In Star Wars Legends (what had been canon before Disney bought it), the Wampa did live, and was actually encountered again by Luke Skywalker when he visited Hoth again.  I believe it was in Children of the Jedi.

Comment: @bubbajake00 Okay, so the Wampa didn't die from exsanguination, either ^^

Comment: [The wampa survived](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxAYii0TDSw)

Comment: Because Han hadn't shot it first, like poor Greedo.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Four reasons:

1. The wampa might not have been alone (remember, the Rebels didn't know much about life on the planet, having only recently arrived, and Luke likely would have had no idea if wampas were solitary or not). He didn't want to find out.
2. In order to be rescued, Luke would have to be found. Being in a cave means he won't easily be found.
3. Luke is injured and cold. He is disoriented, and probably not thinking entirely straight.
4. He was possibly being guided by the force - he did have a force vision shortly after (props to Robobear)

Comment: Also, Jedi don't kill if they can avoid it.

Comment: @JollyJoker: Technically speaking he's not a Jedi, yet. But yes: Probably his chances of becoming one would be worse if he had another mindset.

Comment: "*no idea there was any life on the planet*"... which begs the question of how it came to be named.

Comment: @Simba Wampas might exist elsewhere

Comment: @Simba How it came to be named Hoth? What's that got to do with life, does Hoth mean something?

Comment: The rebels didn't have "no idea there was any life on the planet". They're riding around on tauntauns, which are native to Hoth.

Comment: @Benubird I assume Simba means "how it came to be named a Wampa", not "how it came to be named Hoth". Which is what I was wondering.

Comment: In a deleted scene C-3PO tears a warning sign off a door as they're leaving, and then some stormtroopers open the door only to have a wampa grab one of them. So the rebels knew about the wampas - they had captured one.

Comment: 4. Because Hollywood, would have been a more boring scene if he'd stayed in the cave.

Comment: *having only recently **alive*** or *having only recently **arrived***?

Comment: I would also add that he was having visions of Ben Kenobi, and may have been responding to promptings from the Force concerning what he was doing.

Comment: 2. Being found is useless if you are dead. If ever in a survival situation, surviving must take priority over being found. Surviving for weeks in a cave increases your chance of being found over standing in a blizzard for minutes before you freeze.

Comment: @Luke I'm not saying its a smart decision - but it might be part of Skywalker's reasoning

Comment: I think just fear is a good reason, if I get dragged into a bear cave and almost eaten I'm going to get out as soon as possible even if I cut it's paw off and its freezing outside. Fight or flight.

Comment: To add to point 3 - if he was already suffering from hypothermia, he would be prone to making poor decisions, like letting the "I must get back to the base" thought override his more logical "I can't possibly do that on foot in a blizzard" thoughts.

Comment: Also, even if there was a blizzard outside, the cave might still have been cold enough to kill him in the course of the night. Wookiepedia: "[Hoth's] temperature, although always frigid, was known to drop to -60°C come nightfall". So make that -40°C in the cave. That's not cozy.